# Compare two hashes in perl and list which records are extra?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, comparison

I have two text files that contain user records. I have to compare these two files and figure out which users are missing from File1. And delete these Orphans from file2.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Text::Diff;
use List::Compare;
use Data::Dumper;

my $Users1 = "Users1.txt";
my $Users2 ="Users2.txt";
my %hash1;
my %hash2;
my %new_hash;
my @sorted_1;
my @sorted_2;
my @list_keys1;
my @list_keys2;

open(my $fh1, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $Users1) or die "Colud not open the file!";

while(my $record1 = <$fh1>)
{
    chomp $record1;
    my @list1 = split( '/', $record1);

    foreach my $item(@list1)
    {
        $new_hash{$list1[1]} = $list1[0];
        $hash1{$list1[1]} = $list1[0];
    }
    while ( my ($key, $value) = each(%hash1) ) {
    push (@list_keys1, $key);
    @sorted_1 = sort @list_keys1;
    }

}
print "\t\tHash values for USERS1:\n";
print Dumper \%hash1;

open(my $fh2, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $Users2) or die "Colud not open the file!";

while(my $record2 = <$fh2>)
{
    chomp $record2;
    my @list2 = split( '/', $record2);
    foreach my $item(@list2)
    {
        $hash2{$list2[1]} = $list2[0];

    }

    while ( my ($key, $value) = each(%hash2) )
    {
        push (@list_keys2, $key);
        @sorted_2 = sort @list_keys2;
    }
}
print "\n\n\t\tHash values for Users2:\n";
print Dumper \%hash2;

@hash1{@list_keys1} = 1;
@hash2{@list_keys2} = 1;

foreach(keys %hash2)
{
    print "\nThis user does not exist(to be deleted): $_\n" unless exists $hash1{$_};

}

foreach (keys %hash1)
{
    print "\nNew User (to be added):$_\n" unless exists $hash2{$_};
}

close ($fh1);
close ($fh2);
```

**Questions:**

1. I am not able to sort the user ID (String) alphabetically(here, USER IDs are random strings of length 7). Is there any limitations when it comes to sorting array/hashes in Perl?
2. I am not able to compare two hashes and get the differences. What would be the most efficient way to do that?
3. Are there any additional libraries that I need to install in order to handle this part of code?

**Sample records from file:**

File1: 
ASIA/ASEDF46 
INDIA/PSDfT5V 
CHINA/FSDfT5V 
INDIA/AA44TYB 
USA/BBRTT67

File 2: 
INDIA/PSDfT5V 
CHINA/FSDfT5V 
INDIA/AA44TYB 
USA/BBRTT67 
UK/ZK9EELO

Comment: Update your question to include some sample data from both files.

Comment: I love how you keep sorting all those one-element arrays. Also, `keys \$hash2` should be `keys %$hash2`

Comment: I am getting error that says "Global symbol "$hash2" requires explicit package name...

Comment: You have a few scoping problems. And you don't declare or define `$hash2` so the line `foreach my $key2 (keys $hash2) {` generates the error you describe. Did you mean to use `%new_hash` instead of `$hash2`? Please can you show a sample of your input files?

Comment: @SalyP: If we are to help you with your problems then you must show *all* of your code. How are we to know whether an error is truly a problem, or is simply a result of you removing some code?

Comment: @SalyP: Three lines of one file isn't anywhere near enough to test with. Please show *two* sets of file contents, with enough data to see entries missing from `file1`. Is there really any reason to split the records into two fields? That is, is there a possibility that there will be two entries like `LONDON/WSD48F` and `QUEBEC/WSD48F`? I assume the second part is a user ID?

Comment: @Borodin I do not have much sample data with me right now. I am trying to work with these2files:
File1: ASIA/ASEDF46
INDIA/PSDfT5V
CHINA/FSDfT5V
INDIA/AA44TYB
USA/BBRTT67

File 2:
INDIA/PSDfT5V
CHINA/FSDfT5V
INDIA/AA44TYB
USA/BBRTT67
UK/ZK9EELO
I wish to split it at "/" because I am searching the records based on user ID. After successful implemtation on these sample text files, I wish to implement this code on server where I am coparing two user lists and I have to delete the users from list2 that no longer exist in list1. and this deletion requires Domain name (the part of text before "/").

Comment: @Borodin I have made a few changes to the code and I am able to print the missing user ID in the output. Can you guide me on how to push these user ID's and relevant domain names to a new hash>
PS: Please find the complete n updated code ^ in the question above.

Comment: @Borodin the records are like "<Domain_name>/User ID"..where domain names repeat but IDs are unique. I have created hashes with ID=>key and domain=> value

Comment: @SalyP: Please update your question to include the data that you have posted in your comment above.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt'; 
open my $in2, '<', 'in_2.txt';

my (%data1, %data2);

while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    my @split = split/\//;
    $data1{$split[0]} = $split[1];
}

while(<$in2>){
    chomp;
    my @split = split/\//;
    $data2{$split[0]} = $split[1];
}


foreach(sort keys %data1){
    print "User: $_ Value: $data1{$_}\n" if $data2{$_};
}
```